# Send demo sms via Twilio android eclipse

Tags: android, sms, twilio

i am new to android and trying to send message via twilio in android application.
i have the SID and auth token.

Here is my simple xml code.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Message"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="TO" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="From" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:text="Message" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Message"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Send Message" />
```

Here is the java source provided by Twilio...

```
package com.example.twilio_poc;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
      import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse;
  import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.SmsFactory;
  import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
   import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Sms;


public class SendNotifications {
/* Twilio REST API version */
public static final String ACCOUNTSID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static final String AUTHTOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

public static void main(String args[]){

    /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);

    // Get the account and call factory class
    Account acct = client.getAccount();
    SmsFactory smsFactory = acct.getSmsFactory();

    //build map of server admins
    Map<String,String> admins = new HashMap<String,String>();
    admins.put("4158675309", "Johnny");
    admins.put("4158675310", "Helen");
    admins.put("4158675311", "Virgil");

    String fromNumber = "YYY-YYY-YYYY";

    // Iterate over all our server admins
    for (String toNumber : admins.keySet()) {

        //build map of post parameters 
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("From", fromNumber);
        params.put("To", toNumber);
        params.put("Body", "Bad news " + admins.get(toNumber) + ", the server is down and it needs your help");

        try {
            // send an sms a call  
            // ( This makes a POST request to the SMS/Messages resource)
            Sms sms = smsFactory.create(params);
            System.out.println("Success sending SMS: " + sms.getSid());
        }
        catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

i have no idea what and how should i do this.
so if you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just for your GUI form. You need to implement some Java code. I am sure they have sample java code out there. Look up how to tie buttons to events. That is where you can put the java code that let's you interact with twilio.

Comment: this source for desktop version of java. You should look for android sample code. I don't have my environment setup as of now as I developed an appb1 year ago and I use twilii from c# on windows.